# shell scripting no such file or directory

Tags: shell, ffmpeg, centos, nosuchfileexception

I wrote a shell script that calls the ffmpeg tool but when I run it, it says No such file or directory yet it does!

Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

MAIN_DIR="/media/sf_data/pipeline"

FFMPEG_DIR="/media/sf_data/livraison_transcripts/ffmpeg-git-20180208-64bit-static"

for file in MAIN_DIR/audio_mp3/*.mp3;
do
    cp -p file FFMPEG_DIR;
done

for file in FFMPEG_DIR/*.mp3;
do
    ./ffmpeg -i ${file%.mp3}.ogg
    sox $file -t raw --channels=1 --bits=16 --rate=16000 --encoding=signed-
integer --endian=little ${file%.ogg}.raw;
done

for file in FFMPEG_DIR/*.raw;
do
    cp -p file MAIN_DIR/pipeline/audio_raw/;
done
```

and here is the debug response:

```
cp: cannot stat ‘file’: No such file or directory
./essai.sh: line 14: ./ffmpeg: No such file or directory
sox FAIL formats: can't open input file `FFMPEG_DIR/*.mp3': No such file or 
directory
cp: cannot stat ‘file’: No such file or directory
```

FYI I'm running CentOS7 on VirtualBox

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (MCVE), a version of your script that removes everything not required to show the problem:

```
#!/bin/bash
MAIN_DIR="/media/sf_data/pipeline"
echo MAIN_DIR
```

Expected output:

```
/media/sf_data/pipeline
```

Actual output:

```
MAIN_DIR
```

This is because `bash` requires a `$` when expanding variables:

```
#!/bin/bash
MAIN_DIR="/media/sf_data/pipeline"
echo "$MAIN_DIR"
```

The quotes are not required to fix the issue, but prevent issues with whitespaces.

Answer (score 0):

Hi You need couple of correction in your shell script see below. To get the actual value assigned to a variable you need to add `$` at the front of the variable in shell script.

```
for file in $"MAIN_DIR"/audio_mp3/*.mp3;
do
   cp -p "$file" "$FFMPEG_DIR";
done

for file in "$FFMPEG_DIR"/*.mp3;

./ffmpeg -i ${file%.mp3}.ogg
#provide full path like /usr/bin/ffmpeg

for file in "$FFMPEG_DIR"/*.raw;
do
   cp -p "$file" "$MAIN_DIR"/pipeline/audio_raw/;
done
```

Comment: You're missing a `do` and a `done` before and after the `ffmpeg` command.  `${file%.mp3}.ogg` should also be quoted.